# Ambient occlusion results in reverse / Inverted colours?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Im confused , this has never happened before!

The ambient occlusion is giving a reverse effect , instead of white in exposed areas it turns black?!

[image]

Comment: To be honest, it looks like it is working perfectly in the viewport . . .

Answer (score 1):

this is because of the inverted normals.
you can recalculate the normals by going to edit mode and and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or by pressing recalculate normals from the tool shading panel
[image]

Comment: I wrote the asnwer myself "never mind , i found out it was under a roof , and it gave the object no light to reflect off" , But it got deleted